Baugh-Wooley 5x4 multiplier
I am studying for my exam, but the professor never really explain how Baugh-Wooley works and whenever I try to look it up, there are only research papers on improving it, not actually explaining the concept.
Design a 2's complement 5x4 multiplier using Baugh-Wooley
I know that for example:
(a_0 * x_4)' = x_4*(1 - a_0) - x_4 = a_4*a_0' - x_4
and you can then add x_4 in the next row and add x_4' in the current one.
However I do not understand the approach he takes to reducing "unnecessary values"
Would be great if someone could explain that to me :)
My approach so far

Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?  for more details.

https://math.stackexchange.com/ for mathematical explanations you are looking for?

@MarcLeBihan well it's for computer arithmetic to then convert to code, so I thought about asking it here
